# How do I use string array as parameter in Scala udf?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My Spark dataframe (created from a Hive table) looks like:

```
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|racist|filtered                                                                                                                                                      |
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|false |[rt, @dope_promo:, crew, beat, high, scores, fugly, frog, , https://time.com/sxp3onz1w8]                                                                      |
|false |[rt, @axolrose:, yall, call, kermit, frog, lizard?, , https://time.com/wdaeaer1ay]                                                                                |
```

and I am trying to remove urls from the filtered field.

I have tried:

```
val regex = "(https?\\://)\\S+".r

def removeRegex( input: Array[String] ) : Array[String]  = {
    regex.replaceAllIn(input, "")
}

val removeRegexUDF = udf(removeRegex)

filteredDF.withColumn("noURL", removeRegexUDF('filtered)).show
```

which gives this error:

```
<console>:60: error: overloaded method value replaceAllIn with alternatives:
  (target: CharSequence,replacer: scala.util.matching.Regex.Match => String)String <and>
  (target: CharSequence,replacement: String)String
 cannot be applied to (Array[String], String)
           regex.replaceAllIn(input, "")
                 ^
```

I am very much a newbie at Scala so any guidance you can give on how to handle the filtered array in the udf is much appreciated.
(Or if there is a better way of doing this I'm happy to hear it).

Comment: Your input is an Array of Strings, but the method expects just a single string in which every occurence of the regex is replaced.

Comment: this is not really related to spark, but a pure scala issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not replace the URLs with empty strings but rather remove them. This UDF will do the trick:

```
val removeRegexUDF = udf(
  (input: Seq[String]) => input.filterNot(s => s.matches("(https?\\://)\\S+"))
)
```

Comment: Thanks that did it!

Comment: Can I add an OR in the s.matches bit so it is removed if it matches (URL OR something else)?

Comment: @schoon if course, i would to it like this : `filterNot(s => s.matches(regex1) || s.matches(regex2))`

Comment: Nice catch :) Non-standard thinking is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

At first, instead of Array the type should be Seq or WrappedArray.
Secondly, function changes only one string to other string - not collection.

Your UDF should be:

```
def removeRegex(input: Seq[String]) : Array[String]  = {
    input.map(x => regex.replaceAllIn(x, "")).toArray
}
```

So map each element applying regular expression on it.

You can also use function [regexp_replace](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@regexp_replace(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,replacement:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) from Spark functions

Comment: Thanks. That gave me this error: <console>:61: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[String]
 required: Array[String]
           input.map(regex.replaceAllIn(_, ""))

Comment: @schoon Are you using Scala Regexp?

Comment: @ T. er i think maybe not. I should be importing it right? But i am not.

Comment: @schoon You don't have to. See now my answer, I've changed code

Comment: Now I get: <console>:64: error: missing argument list for method removeRegex
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `removeRegex _` or `removeRegex(_)` instead of `removeRegex`.
       val removeRegexUDF = udf(removeRegex

Comment: For me it does not show any error, but as I can see you already have an answer :)

Comment: Yes I think it was my mistake, sorry. Really appreciate your help.