# How do I use a regex variable in filterNot in Scala?

Tags: scala

Using Scala I am trying to remove URLs from data as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844672/how-do-i-use-string-array-as-parameter-in-scala-udf) question. And the following code works fine:

```
 val removeRegexUDF = udf(
    (input: Seq[String]) => input.filterNot(s => s.matches("(https?\\://)\\S+" ))

 filteredDF.withColumn("noURL", removeRegexUDF('filtered)).select("racist", "filtered","noURL").show(100, false)
```

Now I want to use a variable instead of the literal regular expression, so I try:

```
        val urls = """(https?\\://)\\S+"""
        val removeRegexUDF = udf(
        (input: Seq[String]) => input.filterNot(s => s.matches(urls ))
```

but this seems to have no effect on the data. I try:

```
val urls = """(https?\\://)\\S+""".r
```

but this gives error:

```
urls: scala.util.matching.Regex = (https?\\://)\\S+
<console>:45: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.util.matching.Regex
 required: String
         (input: Seq[String]) => input.filterNot(s => s.matches(urls) )
```

Any guidance on how to achieve this is much appreciated.

Comment: Either use double backslashes or triple quote marks. In the original code you use double backslashes, so why did you also add triple quotes for `val urls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that has to do with using single quotes vs. triple quotes. In the first example you put additional backslashes to escape the characters while in the latter one you don't need them - wrapping the string with triple quotes is enough.

```scala
println("(https?\\://)\\S+")      // (https?\://)\S+
println("""(https?\\://)\\S+""")  // (https?\\://)\\S+
println("""(https?\://)\S+""")    // (https?\://)\S+
```